# Is there a language with dual indefinite articles?

Tags: grammatical-number, indefinite-article

At university, we have been looking into language change, and seeing how for example "one" was used as the singular indefinite article, which changed into "a", but a question arose about whether or not there exists a language with a dual indefinite article, and if this would then come from "two".

Does anyone know of a language with a dual indefinite article? And does it use the number two or come from it?

Comment: *two* basically is the dual indefinite article.

I'm not sure if it proves much, but in some languages *two* and even *three* are declined according to the number, gender and case of the noun, similar to *one*.  For example in Slavic languages (which generally have no articles though) and in some Allemannic dialects.

Comment: I would love to see some examples.

Comment: *zwei*, *zwo*, *zweier*...  два, две, двух...

Comment: Another but of evidence that *two* is the dual indefinite article: a form of *one* is the singular indefinite article in many if not most languages that have indefinite articles.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: Who uses the word "article" in a way that includes all numerals? "A(n)" is special in English (and resembles the definite article "the") in that it is not optional; "two" on the other hand is optional. It's ungrammatical to omit "a" in "I have a nose" but it is grammatical to say "I have hands" rather than "I have two hands."

Comment: @sumelic In English, in those examples.  There are other situations though like *have dinner* or *move house* or *set up camp*.  And *two* or *a pair of* are almost obligatory in some situations, if somebody asks *Do you have bicycles?* and you have two, it would be misleading to say *Yes, I have some*.

Comment: @sumelic But I don't have a strong opinion about this, I just wanted to preemptively dispell the argument that a dual indefinite article should have an etymology distinct from the number *two*.

Comment: @sumelic English is not the most representative data point because *a(n)* seems like a bastardised *one*.  But in German or Spanish, the number for counting seems like the lemma plus a standard morphological ending, that is, it is the other way around, it seems derived from the form used for the (masc nom) article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ancient Greek arguably has a dual indefinite article *tiné*. Literally it means "some [two things]", and is unrelated to the numeral "two".

To elaborate a bit more: Ancient Greek didn't have mandatory indefinite articles during the Classical period, but the indefinite correlative *tis* was in the process of grammaticalizing into that niche. The dual wasn't particularly productive (or common) by this point, mostly showing up in fixed expressions like "two eyes", but *tis* still had a full declension pattern, including dual forms.

(Note: *tis* is specifically the Attic dialect form; other dialects had *kis* or *sis*.)

Eventually, the singular forms of *tis*-as-indefinite-article were displaced by forms of *hen-* "one"; the plural was unaffected, and the dual had died out completely by that point. But if the dual had survived into Modern Greek, it would presumably have an article based on *tiné* or on *dyo* "two".